# How can I get MDT 2012 Update 1/SCCM 2012 SP1 to NOT apply my OS to D: when using USMT?

Tags: partition, sccm-2012, mdt-2012

I have a UDI deployment task sequence setup with MDT 2012 UPdate 1 and SCCM 2012 SP1, and when I try to deploy Windows 7 to a machine with an OS already on it, WinPE assigns the System Reserved partition the C: drive, and the OS the D: drive. This is fine when I choose to format and partition the disk in UDI, but when I choose to migrate user data (using local hard links), the OS is applied to D: and the OS is then on the D: drive, which we don't want.

How can I get WinPE to ignore the System Reserved and stop assigning it a drive letter? And make the OS partition the C: drive?

Comment: Doesn't the task sequence allow you to modify which partition everything get's put on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for the same thing and came across the answer from Jason Sandys.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ta/configmanagerosd/thread/e9da0a2f-ecb0-49d0-8c28-cd59785abefe

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273375.aspx

I ended up adding a Set Task Sequence Variable step before the Apply Operating System step that sets OSDPreserveDriveLetter=False.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.